# Image without Extension

Tags: php, image, extension-methods, imagemagick-convert

I am getting image from API without Extension.

How can I convert that to .jpg or .png in php?

For example: **http://s7.asdcASD/is/image/SDCsaAS/59567_67106_MAIN**

The last parameter is image name but without extension.

Comment: Your question is unclear, just concatenate the extension to your string

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  "Extensions" barely mean anything in file names, and they mean absolutely nothing in URLs.  If a URL returns an image, then you get an image.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You may check the type with `exif_imagetype()` and add proper extension at the end.

Comment: Also check http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: Its Done . Thank You everyone for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to save the image on disk and then open it, try to concat your string with the extension before saving.

E.g

```
<?php
        $a = "59567_67106_MAIN";
        $b = $a . ".jpg";    
?>
```

Comment: At this point, what exactly is `$b`?  It's not a valid file name, nor is it an existing URL.

Comment: Its Done . Thank You for your response

Comment: It's ok. Have a nice day.